# MACRO VBA Formula's

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have the following formula to total the sums of columns with numbers in them. The formula's which are just sums have worked perfectly, however I am having trouble inputting the last 3 formulas which are not sums if IF formulas that divide to get percentage and the last is just simple subtraction.

```
With wks2
    With .Cells(LastRow + 1, 4)
        .Formula = "=SUM(D7:D" & LastRow & ")"
        .Resize(, 3).FillRight
    End With
    .Calculate
    .Parent.Activate
    With .Cells(LastRow + 1, 9)
        .Formula = "=SUM(I7:I" & LastRow & ")"
        .Resize(, 3).FillRight
    End With
    .Calculate
    .Parent.Activate
    With .Cells(LastRow + 1, 7)
        .Formula = "=IF(RC4=0,IF(RC6=0,0,IF(RC6<>0,1,RC6/RC4)),RC6/RC4)"
        .Resize(, 1).FillRight
    End With
    .Calculate
    .Parent.Activate
    With .Cells(LastRow + 1, 12)
        .Formula = "=IF(RC9=0,IF(RC11=0,0,IF(RC11<>0,1,RC11/RC9)),RC11/RC9)"
        .Resize(, 1).FillRight
    End With
    .Calculate
    .Parent.Activate
    With .Cells(LastRow + 1, 14)
        .Formula = "=RC[-2]-RC[-7]"
        .Resize(, 1).FillRight
    End With
    .Calculate
    .Parent.Activate
End With
```

Comment: 1. `.Resize(, 1).FillRight` does not do anything, as `Resize(,1)` leaves it as one cell and the cell that called it.  2.  On the last 3 use `.FormulaR1C1`